# C++ multiple versions of a defaulted special member functions -- error in MSVC 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The following simple code produces an error in the [newest Visual Studio compiler](http://rextester.com/live/ZTNG25351) (MSVC 2015 Update 2):

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename ... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) != 0> > 
    Foo(Args ...) {}
    Foo() = default;  // error

    //Foo() {}        //this works!
};
```

The error message is

> error C2580: 'Foo::Foo(void)': multiple versions of a defaulted special member functions are not allowed

[gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/898a0168482a5602) accepts it without any problems.

This seems to me as an obvious bug (in the sense that it is not supported by the standard). Any other views?

Comment: Only slightly related: I am so unimpressed with UPD2 of VS2015 it is almost laughable, were it not for all the things that have broken @ work as a result of that steaming pile. Related: clang eats this up no problem as well.

Comment: I guess this is because of lack of two-phase lookup? Oh who am I kidding I have no idea. I stopped following developments in the _real_ steaming pile (i.e. C++) some time ago.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. In case you are interested in a workaround, you could make it `template <typename Arg, typename... Args> Foo(Arg, Args...);` This is perhaps a more straightforward way to ensure that the templated constructor takes at least one argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in VS 2015 Update 2. We've already fixed the bug (202164, though that's an internal bug number.) This code should work in Update 3 builds.

Comment: If you are interested in verifying for yourself, we (the MS C++ compiler team) put internal compiler builds up on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ so people can test stuff like this in the browser.

Comment: Would you be able to give a little more information on the bug? What _is_ the bug, actually? That way, visitors to this page with a similar but marginally different problem will know whether your bug fix sorts it out for _them_, too.